# Cisco 2921 SEC upgradable to WAAS?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, waas

Does anyone know if it is possible to upgrade a Cisco2921-SEC/K9 to Cisco2921-AX/K9 (WAAS)? I mean is it the same hardware and all I need is to upgrade the licence?

/Andreas

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it should be; I believe you need this license:  FL-C2921-WAASX

BTW, there is also an minimum RAM increase requirement to run WAAS. Make sure you consult this Cisco [data sheet for WAAS Express](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/routers/wide-area-application-services-waas-express/datasheet_c78-611644.html)